# Registering multiple restplus blueprints on same prefix doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

So I'm building an API with Flask-RestPlus and using blueprints to divide the code into smaller chunks, but when trying to register multiple API endpoint, providing same URL prefix, only one blueprint registers.

Blueprint Templates:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

tmpl_bp = Blueprint('templates_api', __name__)
api = Api(tmpl_bp)

ns_tmpl = api.namespace('templates', description='Templates operations')

@ns_tmpl.route('/')
class Templates(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return "All templates"

    def post(self):
        return "Added/updated template"
```

Blueprint Render:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

rend_bp = Blueprint('render_api', __name__)
api = Api(rend_bp)

ns_render = api.namespace('render', description='Render actions')

@ns_render.route('/')
class Render(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return "Rendering everything"
```

The main app code, where registering happens:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

from api.templates import tmpl_bp
from api.render import rend_bp

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(tmpl_bp, url_prefix="/api/v1")
app.register_blueprint(rend_bp, url_prefix="/api/v1")


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "This is the main page"
```

The resulting Swagger API:
[image]

I was expecting both the Templates and the Render blueprints to be served on `/api/v1/` as `/api/v1/templates` and `/api/v1/render` respectively. But only one registers every time.

How do I get both blueprints served under the same prefix?

Comment: I believe that's how blueprints are supposed to work. What is the benefit of having every resource as a separate blueprint anyway? I was able to do what you are after with just one single blueprint called `APIBlueprint`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Blueprint, it's enough to use flask_restplus Namespaces.
Flask-RESTPlus provides a way to use almost the same pattern as Flask's blueprint. The main idea is to split your app into reusable namespaces.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
from api.templates import tmpl_bp
from api.render import rend_bp

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_namespace(tmpl_bp, path="/api/v1/templates")
api.add_namespace(rend_bp, path="/api/v1/render")


@api.route('/')
def home():
   return "This is the main page"
```

You can find out more details here https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html